# Doing an audio loop on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio, media

I have a track I want to play 'megadeth', I'm calling it by:

```
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.megadeth);
```

And playing it by using 'mp.start'.

And I just want to know, how can I get this audio mp3 to loop?

Comment: Code a loop to start the song again when its finished?

Comment: Yeah... How can I do this? :)

Comment: A link-only answer [provided this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping(boolean)); it may be deleted by the Review Queue, so I am preserving it here.

Answer (score 16):

Before adding

`mp.start();`

Add

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.megadeth);
    mp.setLooping(true);
```

the mp.setLooping(true); automatically allows the raw file to be used over and over again.

Comment: Would this be the same as calling mp.start() again?